# Why part of debroglie wave is negative?

Tags: wave-particle-duality

I mean de Broglie wave for a particle represents the probability of the particle existing at a point, then, how can it be negative as well as positive?

Comment: The de Broglie wave itself does not describe the probability of a particle and it's not real, either. In Schroedinger QM the wave is complex and the probability is its absolute value. Are you talking about Bohm's interpretation of QM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong, what represents the probability is the square of the wave, which is always positive. There is still no agreement on the  physical interpretation or the meaning of the wave itself, that is still an intense field of debate on the foundations of quantum mechanics.

Comment: So when we say particle waves interfere what exactly are we talking about?

Comment: @Sam: We are talking about a widely observed phenomenon that is described correctly using QM. The difficulty that most people have is based on their idea that somehow all concepts from classical mechanics are fundamental and that they should be reflected in nature at all levels. In reality it's the other way around: QM is fundamental and classical mechanics is merely a special case of QM.

Comment: Schrodinger waves interact linearly, that is, at any point in space where the two waves have a value, you add the value of the waves , either of which could be positive or negative, but it is not clear what is the meaning of the wave itself. It is only a useful way to predict the probability of finding the particle at that position, and for that you first add the waves and then take the squares.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory